# How do I find the value in a range based on the value in another range?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

For example

Range1 = 0.6 to 0.7

Range2 = 0.0 to 0.5

When Range1 = 0.6(min) Range2 = 0.5(max)

Inversely when Range1 = 0.7(max) Range2 = 0.0(min)

So lets say the value of Range1 = 0.65, how do I get the value of Range2 from that in the computational simplest way?

Comment: One of the simplest methods is linear interpolation (for which you already have an answer), but without knowing more about the problem you're really trying to solve (what do these ranges represent and what is the purpose of converting from one to the other) it's hard to be sure that this is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out what percentage of the way from $0.7$ to $0.6$ your R1 value is, $$\frac{0.7-x}{0.1}$$
Then multiply that percentage by 0.5 and that's your value you're after.  So the full formula would be $$\frac{0.7-x}{0.1}\times0.5$$
Note that there is an implied addition to $0.0$ as the final step, in case you are looking into generalizing to other ranges.  And the $0.5$ value comes from $0.5-0.0$ and not just from the max value alone of Range2.

Also, this assumes the relationship is linear.